# How to use Metadata validation in blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a project include two project in same Solution Explorer

- First: DbModelContextProvider (Class library)
- Second: AppApiProvider (MVC core api -v3.1.4)

In DbModelContextProvider project i want create Metadata validation for Department

```
public class DepartmentMetaData
{
        [Display(Name = "Department Name")]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then create new class Department but partial class

```
[MetadataType( typeof(DepartmentMetaData))]
 public partial class Department
{
}
```

> Same code use with MVC core web app work success but when i want work
> with Blazor not work

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is not yet supported for Blazor. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20805